# How to call instance variable programmatically

Tags: ios, uievent

The objective is to create a reminder event via [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingReminders/ReadingAndWritingReminders.html). So far I have the instance variable created (and implemented in the header file as well).

```
- (EKReminder *)reminderWithEventStore:(EKEventStore *)eventStore {

    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title     = webTitle;
    event.notes     = urlField.text;

    event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];

    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err;
    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
}
```

How do I create the reminder by executing the code upon clicking a button within a UIActionSheet? I've tried `[self.eventStore:self];` but I'm guessing theres more to it than just that.

Comment: so basically you want to execute your method when a button on an action sheet is tapped ? is this your problem ?

Comment: Well I was also looking for some possible verification with my code, but yes I was wondering what code I would need to execute the `Write Reminder` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You are just adding an event to the default Calendar . The event is added , once you call this function.

Simply Create an Object of `EKEventStore`

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

and call your function :-

```
[self reminderWithEventStore:eventStore];
```

But you are not returning anything in your non-void function :)  , but , the function definition is already documented in iOS API version 6 for [EKReminder Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKReminderClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/EKReminder), which is a class Method.

```
+ (EKReminder *)reminderWithEventStore:(EKEventStore *)eventStore
```

are you trying to override the above method.

You can simply add a reminder in the calendar using above class method.

First you should be clear of your motive , whether you want to add

1 Event

2 Reminder

3 Calendar.

Comment: My apologies! I wish to add a reminder and set the default time to 6 hours from whenever the reminder was clicked. I also wish the set the reminder title and description to that of my NSString values `webTitle` and `urlField`. My apologies for being unclear. :)

Comment: you just have to remove your function and add the code to the viewDidLoad . also you can change the name of the function and a return type is not needed.And for 6 hrs , it should be 6*60*60 in intiWithTineInterval